# ArcGIS Server Py3 - <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, ImportError('No module named arcgis',), <traceback object at 0x00000000025870C8>

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, arcgis-python-api, conda, python-3.7

I have cloned the default python env that installs with ArcGIS Server using conda create in the python command window using:

```
conda create --clone arcgispro-py3 -p"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\py3_envclone2"
```

I activated the cloned env and installed jenkspy

```
(py3_envclone2) C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\py3_envclone2>conda install -c conda-forge jenkspy
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\py3_envclone2:
#
jenkspy                   0.2.0            py37hcc03f2d_1    conda-forge
```

I then spun up the python console using python.exe in command window
and then tested imports of my modules without fail:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> import jenkspy
>>> import json
>>> import arcgis
>>>
```

However, when I run from my script:

```
# need to call pyhton from the environment where ArcGIS allows third party library installs to access all the necessary modules in the script

import sys
    
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\py3_envclone2')
    
# import remaining modules
    
import arcpy, json, jenkspy, arcgis
```

I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File

```
"C:\Desktop\MyScript.py", line 10, in <module>
    import arcpy, json, jenkspy, arcgis
ImportError: No module named jenkspy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should remove the `try` from the code that you present so that we can see the error message and line number that it is coming from.  Also, the error seems to be coming from your `from arcgis import GIS` so to simplify the code that you present, I think you should use a single `import arcgis` (and nothing else) in the code that you present.

Comment: Remove `sys.path.append` from script and then activate your clone before running the script.

Comment: @PolyGeo made the changes you suggested and updated post. Now getting import eror on jenkspy and I assume I would get the error on arcgis subsequently.

Comment: @user2856 removed sys.path.append after activating library and still got the import error (see edited post). Even if this had worked it probably wouldn't be the right solution for me as I need this to run on a scheduled batch.

Comment: Not sure then, your env might not set up correctly. But yes you still need to activate your env, even in a scheduled task. You wrap it in a bat or powershell script that does the activation.

Comment: And make sure you are using the python exe in your env, i.e `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\py3_envclone2\python.exe`